# jQuery Datatable adding parameters to url

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, laravel-5

I have created a datatable, I want to add filter option to url, here is my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 oTable = jQuery('#vV7SyzDr').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "my_url",
    "bServerSide": true,
    "fnServerParams":function ( aoData ) {
        $("select[name=label]").change(function () {
           var labels = $("select[name=label]").val();
           aoData.push({"labels": labels } ); 
        });       
     },
  });

  $("select[name=label]").change(function () {
      oTable.fnDraw();
    });
  });
```

But the url is not triggered with parameter labels. 
I have a multiple select box to filter the table.

```
<select class="tagit-hiddenSelect" name="label" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected" value="Important">Important</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="Bug">Bug</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to add the selected labels to my_url in sAjaxSource, and backed I should get labels and return json response, That will render in my datatable with new data from backend.

Now My url is

```
http://my_domain/filter?sEcho=1&iColumns=7&sColumns=%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=10&mDataProp_0=0&sSearch_0=&bRegex_0=false&bSearchable_0=true&bSortable_0=true&mDataProp_1=1
```

I want to add parameter `label` to my url. Ideally it should be

http://my_domain/filter?sEcho=1&iColumns=7&sColumns=%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=10&mDataProp_0=0&sSearch_0=&bRegex_0=false&bSearchable_0=true&bSortable_0=true&mDataProp_1=1`&label=['important','bug']` (['important','bug'] means value in array type).

Please help me, I am a beginner in front end

Comment: Please, by respect for people who will try to help you, can you format properly your code ?

Comment: Can you better explain what you are trying to do? Its not clear what your doing or what your issue is

Comment: This still doesnt make a lot of sense. What do you mean by **add filter option to url** ? What url? What is a "filter option"? What do all of the   calls to `$("td", nRow).css()` have to do with your question?

Comment: You might be looking for [`columns.render()`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) which will let you read the incomming data from the server and render it however you like

Comment: chi stamu passannu..

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand what you're trying to do, and you've almost got it right - it looks like you've just got the `change` event in the wrong place.  Your datatables initialisation code should look like this:

```
oTable = jQuery('#vV7SyzDr').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "my_url",
    "bServerSide": true,
    "fnServerParams": function(aoData) {
        aoData.push({"labels": $("select[name=label]").val() });
      });
    }
  });
```

Note: All I have done is remove the `change` event binding.

Now you need to bind the datatables `fnDraw` to the selectlist change event. This is not part of the datatables init code, so put it elsewhere in the js :

```
$("select[name=label]").change(function() {
    oTable.fnDraw();
});
```

`fnDraw` will redraw the datatable by calling your ajax service, passing the additional parameter specified in `fnServerParams`.

Comment: I have tried your answer, but not working(even didn't draw the table). I have edited the question. Please have a look

Comment: Yes I am getting an error: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Comment: Is there some code that you're not showing us?  how are you binding the columns?

Comment: Here I am using a package (chumber datatable) for laravel (php framework) . I have update my code and the error has gone.

Comment: But still parameter and value is not added.